# How to disable Taskbar Thumbnail preview in Windows 8 ?

Tags: windows-8, taskbar

When I hover my mouse cursor over a running application's button in the taskbar, small windows appear showing the contents of the open program. How can I disable that? I find it quite annoying.

[image: taskbar thumbnail preview]

Comment: AKA Windows Peek, I love this feature in Vista+... But I am also surprised there are no questions for this yet.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 hit the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> keys (for search) and type in *visual effects* hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and in the Performance Options window uncheck the option *Animations in the Taskbar*. I think this will do the trick.

[image: animations in the taskbar]

Comment: Please +1 and check as answer  :)

Comment: Does not work on Windows 8.1

Comment: @Chris why is it not working ? It should work for Windows 8.1. Are you sure, 100% sure that it is not working ?

Comment: @Devid http://i.stack.imgur.com/aeQE2.png

Comment: @Chris after clicking on apply have you tried to restart your PC ? If yes then this must be a bug. Try then to disable it via the registry: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-turn-off-taskbar-thumbnail-live-previews-in-windows-7/

Comment: @Devid Yes, I restarted my machine after I changed that setting. In the meantime I have also set those two registry keys and restarted but still no luck.

Comment: This doesnt work for me either. Windows 8.1

Comment: Why is this answer getting so many downvotes?  I mean the screenshot is saying to disable the wrong visual effect but that isn't a valid reason to downvote it.

Comment: Not worked for me.  Windows 8.1

Answer (score 20):

On Windows 8.1 you can get rid of it with these settings:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband]
"NumThumbnails"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"ExtendedUIHoverTime"=dword:41fffffe
```

Import them and restart Explorer. See [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-do-i-disable-the-taskbar-thumbnail-previews-in/c1f3262c-5fc9-4ced-a483-b50959a83a0f).

Comment: Awesome, I was about to answer this, and then it turns out my answer is already linked here :)

Comment: this solution worked for me.

Comment: I don't see the point of the `NumThumbnails` entry when the underlying mechanism here is just `ExtendedUIHoverTime` making it take a very long time to show up.

Comment: Indeed, you don't need `NumThumbnails`. Other than that, this is how you fix it on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Confirmed working on WS2012 R2 and Win8.1, thanks Op!

Comment: This worked on Windows 10.

Comment: yup, works on win10 for me too.

Answer (score 6):

A few options (I've only tested option 4):

**[Option 1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b56e848b-ef2f-448c-961b-37ac5c27fd75/disable-thumbnail-popups-on-task-bar?forum=w8itprogeneral):** (I haven't tested this one)

1. Click on Start button and type RegEdit in Instant Search text box,
   then hit Enter.
2. In the Registry Editor, navigate to the following registry key:
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

   Note: If Explorer registry sub-key does not exist, then right click
   on Policies and click New -> Key and name it as “Explorer”.
3. In the right pane, right click and select New -> DWORD (32-bit)
   Value.
4. Type `TaskbarNoThumbnail` as the name for the new registry value
   data.
5. Double click on `TaskbarNoThumbnail` to modify its value data.
6. Type 1 and click on OK.
7. Restart computer if needed.

   To re-enable Taskbar thumbnails again, just right click on
   TaskbarNoThumbnail and click  Delete to remove the whole registry
   key, or set TaskbarNoThumbnail value data to 0.

**Option 2 and 3:**

Install [7+ Taskbar Tweaker 4.5](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) - This [does work](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-v4-5-with-windows-8-1-update-1-support) on Win 8.1

In the Hovering section, check the box 'nothing'

Install [Taskbar Thumbnails Tuner](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.27) - According to one person who commented on this page (jonesy), it works in Windows 8.1, but I haven't tested.

At the bottom, check the 'Disable thumbnails' box

**Option 4:** (I've tested this one)

1. Open Control Panel > System (in icons view)
2. Click Advanced System Settings on the left
3. Alternatively, you can just search for (win+w) *visual effects*
4. Go to the Advanced tab
5. Click Settings in the Performance area (the top area)
6. Check the Custom box
7. Uncheck the 3rd checkbox - "Animations in the taskbar"

Comment: Is this tested and working in Windows 8 ? Because I think the second option does not work in Windows 8.1.

Comment: The first option is copy-pasted from [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-and-turn-off-taskbar-thumbnail-preview-in-windows-7-switch-to-list-view/) without proper credit. Besides, it only works in Windows Vista.

Comment: @and31415 Sorry about the source, I forgot to link it, I actually got it from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b56e848b-ef2f-448c-961b-37ac5c27fd75/disable-thumbnail-popups-on-task-bar?forum=w8itprogeneral. EDIT: But on second look, it looks like that is the site Exotic Hadron was referring to

Comment: In 8.1, "Animations in the taskbar" doesn't have anything to do with the hover thumbnails.

Comment: @fred It does, which is why Me WowLol accepted Devid's answer

Comment: No it doesn't. Thumbnails still happen with that unchecked. It probably controls the fade-in of the thumbnails, I bet they just appear with no fade if you uncheck it.

Comment: Option #3 DOES work in Windows 8.1 when nothing else listed on this page worked.

Answer (score 2):

Do what it shows in the first example, but instead of unchecking "Animations in the Taskbar";  uncheck "Enable Peek" instead.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 8.1.  Unchecking "Animations in the taskbar" did not.

Comment: This will get rid of the desktop preview, but not the popups when you're over a task button.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Windows 8.1

http://winaero.com/download.php?view.27

Nothing else suggested worked
[image]

Comment: Including the name and a description of the tool in your answer would be useful if, in the future, the link no longer works, which unfortunately does happen.