# How do I disable taskbar window previews in Windows 8.1 ONLY when the widow buttons are combined?

Tags: windows-8

This answer:
[How to disable Taskbar Thumbnail preview in Windows 8 ?](https://superuser.com/questions/755553/how-to-disable-taskbar-thumbnail-preview-in-windows-8)

seems to let me know how to disable thumbnails when I hover my mouse over a window on the taskbar. I generally like this.

I don't like it, however, when I have more than 3 PDFs open in Adobe Acrobat (each open in a separate window, which is my preference). In Windows 7, I would hover my mouse over the one Adobe Acroboat Reader button on the taskbar (ie which would be combining multiple window buttons), and then instead of any preview, it would stack vertically the filename of each document.

These filenames would be long and often would be Prefixed with the same characters (ie the college course code), but that was fine because I could see the entire filename.

In Windows 8.1, when I hover my mouse over a combined window button on the taskbar, it expands many thumbnails side-by-side (ie horizontally), thus cutting off the filename.

I want to disable thumbnail previews only for combined window buttons. How can I do this?

Comment: check this page. http://superuser.com/questions/755553/how-to-disable-taskbar-thumbnail-preview-in-windows-8

Comment: I cannot find a suggestion on that page that does what I need. All those suggestions seem to be about disabling thumbnails entirely, instead of disabling them only when hovering over a combined group of windows.